# Microsoft Graph API return ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I use the Microsoft Graph API to crawl emails in Exchange Online.
If you try to crawl the ArchiveMsgFolderRoot folder using this API, you will get a ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId error.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id/mailFolders/ArchiveRoot/
```

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: ce60b00e-1703-450e-b8d2-0e8629519985
client-request-id: ce60b00e-1703-450e-b8d2-0e8629519985
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Japan East","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_5"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Mon, 18 May 2020 06:40:06 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 257

{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId",
    "message": "Item Id doesn't belong to the current mailbox.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "ce60b00e-1703-450e-b8d2-0e8629519985",
      "date": "2020-05-18T06:40:07"
    }
  }
}
```

The error did not return at least around March.
The same applies to the following folders.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id/mailFolders/ArchiveMsgFolderRoot/`
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id/mailFolders/ArchiveDeletedItems/`

Has the Microsoft Graph folder naming scheme changed?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible: [The API does not support accessing in-place archive mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0), not on Exchange Online nor on Exchange Server.

That's why neither ArchiveMsgFolderRoot nor ArchiveDeletedItems is not listed under the [Well-known folder names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Finally, [Cross-mailbox API calls will fail](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/accessing-outlook-items-in-a-users-archived-shared-or-delegated-mailboxes-using-microsoft-graph/) starting April 15, 2020.

Comment: Thanks Alfredo.
My system is failing due to an apparent change in the Microsoft Graph API, specifically cross-mailbox API calls that used to work now fail.
Are there any alternatives to the Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: @aptenodytes none that support this.